# How to estimate a chance of getting in the first positions, given previous tries?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, expected-value

I perform a series of experiments that return a number N that is between 1 and MAX. MAX varies between experiments. For example:

```
6 out of 79
10 out of 204
22 out of 278
43 out of 413
126 out of 1489
86 out of 4846
```

Now, I have a new experiment. MAX is known in advance. I want to know what are is the chance of N ending up between 1 and 10 (or some other arbitrary number).

Comment: There's not enough information to know. How does "$N$" arise? Is it a count of successes of some even with constant probability, for example? Is it something else?

Comment: @Glen_b the source data is a set of lists ordered by element score plus some random factor.

Comment: I'm trying to provide some kind of an estimate for an element position in a search results list. I know that for the past searches the element had positon 6 (out of 79 results), 10 (out of 204), and so on. I also know that the next search has MAX results, and I want to estimate what's the chance of getting in the top 10 results there.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a typical [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) problem - given one variable (here: $MAX$) you want to predict the other (here: $N$).

As there are only two dimensions, it is possible to visualize this data on a scatter plot, so you may notice a pattern.

The easiest way to go is to start with **linear regression**; perhaps you need to take **logarithm** of variables (you need to test it).

If you only care if $N \leq 10$, then use **logistic regression**. That way you will get estimation of probability that $N \leq 10$, given $MAX$.

There are myriad of other ways to do it, but without more information about your data it's hard to advise anything more specific. But the easiest step forward is to play with variable scaling - especially [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform).

Comment: Are there any other possible approaches to this? With regression I will get weird results in some cases. Imagine I have two results: 50 of 100, and 50 of 1000. Any kind of regression will suggest that N is independent of MAX and for MAX < 50 will give me a chance of 0% that N<=10. Which is not true, because for MAX<10 the chance of N<=10 is 100%.

Comment: I'm considering another approach here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160811/given-a-set-of-numbers-from-0-to-100-whats-the-chance-that-the-next-number-wil