# Given a set of numbers from 0 to 100, what's the chance that the next number will be less than 10?

Tags: variance, expected-value

I performed a set of trials. Every trial returned a number 0<=N<100. What's the chance that in the next trial, the picked number will be less than 10?

Comment: There's not enough information here to give an answer (you may be making assumptions that aren't stated in your question)

Comment: Thanks, @Glen_b , what kind of extra information do I need?

Comment: 1. The relative probabilities or densities of the numbers. 2. Whether the numbers are integers, or have a lattice distribution but with a difference other than 1 (e.g. 0,10,20,...90,100), or are discrete but not on a lattice, or are continuous, or mixed, ... 3. what the dependence structure is between trials. e.g. do you mean independent trials with equiprobable numbers selected from the integers 0,1,2,...,100?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not responded to questions and it has been years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to estimate probability distribution from which it comes (with some educated guesses and then optimizing parameters).

A good place to start reading would be [Cam Davidson-Pilon "Probabilistic Programming & Bayesian Methods for Hackers"](http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/).